# jQuery datatables - Complex Headers with 3 row of Header - AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am trying to create a [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) with a complex header, so there will be a complex header with this-

[image]

With custom Column Search Boxes and Column Visiblity Options like this -

[image]

So I what I like to have is something like this-

[image: asdasd]

So What I have done is changed my headers of HTML to this-

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                    <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Joining date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="0"  class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td  valign="middle"><input  readonly="readonly" type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input datepicker" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

From This-

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Joining date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="0"  class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td  valign="middle"><input  readonly="readonly" type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input datepicker" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

But then my AJAX got stopped. No AJAX is working. So I get a output like this-

[image]

Can anyone help me, what I have done wrong?

===========================================================================

If U like to have full code, here is this-

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
        <table id="employee-grid"  class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                    <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th>Joining date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="0"  class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td  valign="middle"><input  readonly="readonly" type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input datepicker" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable(
    {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        //ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource for AJAX Data

        "ajax":
        {
            "url": "employee-grid-data.php",
            //"type": 'POST',
            "data": function ( d )              //Sending Custom Data for manupulating with elements out of the table
                    {
                        d.myKey = "myValue";
                        // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                        // etc
                    }
        },

        "pagingType": "full_numbers",   //Adding Last and First in Pagination
        stateSave: true,
        "language":{                    //Custom Message Setting
                        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",    //Customizing menu Text
                        "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",             //Customizing zero record text - filtered
                        "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",           //Customizing showing record no
                        "infoEmpty": "No records available",                //Customizing zero record message - base
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"   //Customizing filtered message
                    },
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],        //For customizing number of data sets per page

        dom: 'l<"toolbar">Bfrtip',  //"Bfrtip" is for column visiblity - B F and R become visible
        initComplete:   function()  //Adding Custom button in Tools
                        {
                            $("div.toolbar").html('<button type="button" onclick="addNewEntry()">Add a New Record</button>');
                        },
        orderCellsTop: true,            //Column Visiblity Buttons - Visual Reorganising - Bug Fixing
        buttons:    [                   //Column Visiblity Buttons
                        {
                            extend: 'colvis',
                            collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
                            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
                        }
                    ],

    });                 

    $("#employee-grid_filter").css("display","none");  // hiding global search box

    //Custom Search Boxes-Start////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $('.employee-search-input').on( 'keyup change', function ()
    {   
        var i =$(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
        var v =$(this).val();       // getting search input value
        dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
    } );
    //Custom Search Boxes-End//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Date Picker Adding and Options-Start///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showOn: "button",
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        showButtonPanel: true ,
        autoSize: true,
        buttonImage: "//jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        closeText: "Clear"
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".ui-datepicker-close", function()
    {
        $('.datepicker').val("");
        dataTable.columns(5).search("").draw();
    });
    //Date Picker Adding and Options-End///////////////////////////////////////////////

});

function addNewEntry()
{
    $("#addNewData").modal({}).draggable();
    $(".modal-body")
    $('#addNewData').modal('show');
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddles that replicate the bug? www.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sure - I am creating the JSFiddles right now

Comment: Sorry, I can't run PHP file there, So I am sharing my github repo for the whole code-  https://github.com/abrarjahin/DataTables-AdvancedUse

Comment: I think it will make more sense, waiting for your help

Comment: Before i look at anything, it's sort of weird to have 2 rows of <th>. Plus, since those <th> you added are the problem, why don't you remove them, and add them back as a simple div, above your <table>? Also, you're only supposed to have <thead> surrrounding <th>, and optionally <tbody> surrounding <td>.

Comment: I need it, So I am trying to do it.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

`orderCellsTop` is the real problem here because you use middle row for sorting, there is no configuration option for that yet.

> **SOLUTION**

You needs to put your `input` elements into the row with headings and use the bottom one for sorting.

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" valign="bottom">
            Name<br>
            <input type="text" id="0"  class="employee-search-input">
         </th>
        <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
        <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
           Position<br>
           <input type="text" id="2"  class="employee-search-input">
        </th>
        <th>
           City<br>
           <input type="text" id="3"  class="employee-search-input">
        </th>
        <th>
           Age<br>
           <input type="text" id="4"  class="employee-search-input">
        </th>               
        <th>
           Joining date<br>
           <input  readonly="readonly" type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input datepicker" >
        </th>
        <th>
           Salary<br>
           <input type="text" id="6"  class="employee-search-input">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Also you need to prevent sorting when `input` elements are clicked.

```js
$('#example thead .employee-search-input').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a1e48sp/4/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank for your kind help

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to reload datatable data with ajax (resend request). I have tried $('#employee-grid').DataTable().ajax.reload(); and $('#employee-grid').DataTable().fnReloadAjax(); But none of them are working. Can u please help?